# Returning filter with relational data to Laravel view

Tags: laravel

Currently my index method works and looks like this:

```
return view('books.index', [
    'books' => Book::with(['author', 'publisher'])->paginate(15)
]);
```

But I would like to use filter() to filter results upon request, this is my best shot so far:

```
return view('books.index', [
    'books' => Book::latest()
        ->filter(request(['search']))
        ->with(['author', 'publisher'])
        ->paginate(15)
        ->withQueryString()
]);
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::filter()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Laravel you have a filter helper. But this works only in collection and not as query builder.

```
$books = Book::latest()
   ->with(['author', 'publisher'])
   ->paginate(15);

$filteredBooks = $books->filter(function ($value) {
    return $value == request(['search']);
})

dd($filteredBooks);
```

Comment: @Xelerate I updated my answear. My mistake it should be only pass `$value` and not `$value` and `$key`.